# How can I turn my LaTeX into a black and white (1 bit) bitmap image?

Tags: printing

I have a LaTeX document with only text in it. I want to prepare it for printing at printshop, and they need it in a black and white 1 bit bitmap image format, for example a 1 bit tiff, at 300 dpi.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: A print shop that cannot handle vector graphical PDF?!?

Comment: I don't think this is a LaTeXy question. _Any_ way how to convert _any_ PDF into such shape would do.

Comment: @daleif It's for an old Riso printer, so it's better to convert it yourself then to have control over it.

Comment: @yo' Yea, you're right, just thought if there was some LaTeX compiler that had the option to output a bitmap or something like that. Maybe close this as off topic and I'll ask for a solution with Imagemagick instead :)

Answer (score 1):

Ghostscript can do the job, e.g. PNG files with black and white:

```
$ gs -sDEVICE=pngmono -sOutputFile=test%d.png -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE test.pdf
```

If the document `test.pdf` has two pages, then the files `test1.png` and `test2.png` are created.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ghostscript to do this:

```
gs -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -r300 -o output%02d.tif input.pdf
```

`-sDEVICE=tiffg4` means use the monochrome G3 fax encoding [output device](http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Devices.htm). See also `tiffsep` output device, which you can use if you want to separate in CMYK.

`-r300` means 300 dpi.

`-o output%02d.tif` gives you filenames corresponding to the page number of the the pdf (*output01.pdf*, *output02.pdf* and so on).